# x86 linux - how to create custom malloc with address hint

Tags: c, x86, memory-management, pthreads

I want to create a custom malloc which allocates memory blocks within a given address range.

I am writing a pthreads application in which threads are bound to unique cores on a many-core machine. The memory controllers are statically mapped, so that certain range of addresses on main memory are electrically closer to a core. 
I want to minimize the latency of communication between cores and main memory by allocating thread memory on these "closer" regions.

Any ideas would be most appreciated.
Thank you!
Nandu

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is already libnuma for that purpose. Take a look at `numa_alloc_onnode`